# Sort an array as values are inputted into the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need help with a loop that will shift the elements of an array if a newly added value is lower than an existing value, so the array is being sorted as new values are inputted.

The array is empty to start with.

I had tried several loops but they don't seem to work in my case as they were loops used for arrays that were already full.

Here is the code I currently have.

```
if(index < 0)
    index = -(index + 1);

if(arr[index] > key)
    for(int i = 0; i < count -1; i++) {
        arr[index + i] = arr[index + i + 1];
    }

arr[index] = key;
```

The index is from a binary search.

So for example, if I have input 80 first, it would take the slot of `arr[0]`. Then I input 45, which will also take the slot of `arr[0]`.

Since 45, key, is smaller than the existing arr[0] (80), 80 is to move up an index.

Comment: Hint to understand what your problem in that code is; we would need to understand how you setup the whole thing. How are index/count getting their values?! It is really confusing to see that index might < 0 in some cases?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want the loop so that it does the following:

1. Shift the elements with indices > index so that you make space for the new element, and
2. then add the element to given index.

```
for (int  i = count; i > index; i--) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1]; // shifts the elements to the one place right
}
arr[index] = key; // add the key to the given index
```

Note: The count is the current number of elements in the array and it is less than arr.length

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Working from the end of the array downwards definitely makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do.

Comment: Sure! Happy to help

Comment: @FiftySentos  Please mark this answer as "correct" so that Jainul gets his due credit and others with the same problem will easily find it.

Comment: You may want to add recreating the array bigger, if its current length is reached.
That's how an ´Arraylist´ works btw, keeping an array internaly and doubling its length when its current capacity is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for something like this:

First of all, you need

1. A counter that tells you how many "unused" array elements are left; there is no point in swapping index 1 to 2, 2 to 3, ... if you find in the end that your array is "full"
2. Keep an eye on the index, to avoid going beyond the length of your array

Then it is really simple:

- You iterate your current array to find the first index (lets call it *n* here) that is bigger than *key*
- Then you turn to the last array index that is "in use" ... and start moving values to the right from there
- Finally, after you moved arr[n] to arr[n+1]; you assign arr[n] = key

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to shift your array elements in the wrong direction.

Given `index = 0` and `i = 0`, you'd end up with:

```
arr[0] = arr[1];
```

When you probably want the other way around.

Comment: `arr[index + i + 1] = arr[index + i]` would make it `arr[1] = arr[0]`?